# Vue.js child component event sometimes will not fire

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, css-animations

I have a component A use v-for render multiple component B, in component B
fire an animationend to A, and in A delete that B

but sometime the animationend won't fire

[code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/animationend-problem-zkgkh)

Comment: From reading the MDN documentation on animationend --- what if it aborts? Should you also listen to animationcancel ?

Comment: I have watched you sandboxed code for a moment and for me looks like all components are being removed so it seems like all animationend events are fired, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
As posva in vuejs official GitHub says:  just use the i as key, problem resolved